# How to demonstrate that [0,1] is a connected set?

Tags: general-topology

to a point, the demonstration is clear for me. I'll sum it up like this:

So firstly I'll try to demonstrate that I=[0,1] is not connected to get to a contradiction, which will conduct to the fact that [0,1] is actually connected.

In case [0,1] is disconnected, that means there are two open sets A and B, so that $A\cap I$, respectively $B\cap I$ that are non-empty, disjoint, and their union is I. (from the definition of disconnected sets)

Without loss of generality, let's say 1 E B we define c=sup($A\cap I$) which means c>=0 and c<=1 which conducts to the fact hat c E [0,1], so c E I which means c E ($A\cap I$)U($B\cap I$) because I is the union of $A\cap I$ and $B\cap I$ from the definition of disconnected sets this means that c E $(AUB)\cap I$ which implies that c E (AUB)

then, there are two cases case 1) c E A case II) c E B

for case I) it says that in this case cE (O,1) * Because A is open and it contains c, then there are points in $A\cap I$ which are higher than c, which contradicts the definition of supremum**

case II) is similar and conducts to a contradiciton as well

*which is where my confusion starts, how do you know for sure that it is (0,1) and not just [0,1) ? **you can know for sure that there is such a point in A(because it's an open set) but how do I know that there is such a point in $A\cap I$ ?

---

in my book i have this definition of connectedness

I is connected if I is not disconnected

I is disconnected if there are two open sets A & B, so that :

i) $A\cap I$ is non empty set

$B\cap I$ is non empty set

ii) ($A\cap I$) U ($A\cap I$) = I

iii) $$A\cap I)\cap (B\cap I$$  is empty set

Comment: Your notation is confusing me.  Rather than use "A^I", I think you want `$A\cap I$`, which displays (thanks to the magic of MathJax) as $A\cap I$.

Comment: I'd say that the hardest part is to find a definition for $[0,1]$ and for " a set is connected" which doesn't imply trivially that $[0,1]$ is connected

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little convoluted, so I'll just answer the question in the title. I hope this helps anyway.

---

Suppose $[0,1]$ can be separated into $A,B$. We can suppose $1 \in B$ without loss of generality.

Let $c:=\sup A$.

Now, $c$ can't belong to $A$, because if it did it would not be $1$ and, since $A$ is open, it would imply that a greater element than $c$ would belong to $A$. But $c$ can't belong to $B$ either, because this would imply either that $c=0$ (from where $A$ would not be open) or that there would exist someone smaller than $c$ in $B$ which would still be an upper bound for $A$, since $B$ is open.

Therefore, $c$ is not in $A$ nor $B$, a contradiction.

Comment: how can [0,1] which is closed, be separated into A and B if A and B are open?

Comment: $A,B$ are open in the subspace topology.

Comment: could you please explain to me what is the difference between open and open in the subspace topology? that would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: @meiznub If $A$ is open in the real numbers, then $A\cap[0,1]$ is called "open in the subspace topology" (where the subspace is $[0,1]$). Conversely, a set $B$ is open in the subspace topology iff there is a set $A$ that's open in the real numbers such that $B=A\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: @meiznub Basically, ignoring the whole subspace topology thing: Suppose $[0,1]$ is separated into $A\cap[0,1]$ and $B\cap[0,1]$ where $A$ and $B$ are open. Assume $1\in B\cap[0,1]$. Define $c$ to be $\sup(A\cap[0,1])$ and find a contradiction.

Comment: could you please explain to me where you find the contradiction, if you go forth with the proof in your last post, because this is where i'm mostly confused. i can't connect the dots between your first explanation(the one that used the concept of "open in the subspace topology") and your last one( which uses exactly the definition in my course) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: more details where my confusion starts: so my course says that if A is open, then there are points in $A\cap [0,1]$ higher than c (for the first case where c is in A) . how do they know that? you only know that A is open and 1 is not in A(because it is B). how do they come up to the conclusion that $A\cap [0,1]$ contains a point higher than c?
your help would be greatly appreciated. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is to show that a path-connected metric space is connected, and then showing $I$ is path-connected is fairly simple. (Then you need to think why the converse, connected implies path-connected, is not true!)

Comment: Showing that a path-connected metric space is connected will go through the fact that $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: It seems so. Good to remember these things

Comment: @AloizioMacedo This makes me wonder: is using that result actually necessary? Or just the most common way to do it?